# Download PDF file with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, download, filesaver.js

I want to download a PDF file that is loaded via AJAX. I tried to do this by using the library [FileSave.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js). The following code works, but when I open the PDF file it is completely empty. I noticed that the encoding of the PDF file is UTF-8 but the endpoint returns a PDF with ANSI encoding.

What do I have to do in order to download the file with the correct encoding?

```
var downloadReport = function() {
    $http.get("../api/report").then( function(response) {

        var blob = new Blob([response.data], {
            type: "application/pdf",
        });
        saveAs(blob, fileName);

    });
};
```

Comment: Can you verify the contents of `blob`?

Comment: The content seems to be correct. The endpoint returns `application/pdf`. When I call the endpoint directly in a browser, then the download works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem by my self. I had to add the `responseType: "arrayBuffer"` to the http request:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '../api/report',
    responseType: "arraybuffer"
    }).then( function(response) {
        var blob = new Blob([response.data], {
            type: "application/pdf",
        });
    saveAs(blob, fileName);
    });
};
```